# Redux: display single record but json is an array

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

My react-redux app is getting a single record in JSON but the record is an array and therefore it looks like this (notice [ ] brackets):

```
{"person":[{"PersonID":1,"Name":"John Smith","Gender":0}]}
```

So, the redux store shows it as person->0->{"PersonID":1,"Name":"John Smith","Gender":0}. As such, the state shows that the person object is empty:

```
Name: this.props.person?this.props.person.Name:'object is empty',
```

My PersonPage.js includes the details page like this:

```
<PersonDetail person={this.props.person} />
```

The details page has this:

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';

class PersonDetail extends React.Component {
   state = {
        Name: this.props.person?this.props.person.Name:'',
        PersonID: this.props.person?this.props.person.PersonID:null,
        loading: false,
        done: false
    }


 componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
      this.setState({
        PersonID: nextProps.person.PersonID,
        Name: nextProps.person.Name

      });
  }
```

This is my raw Redux state:

```
people: [
    [
      {
        PersonID: 51,
        Name: 'John Smith',
        Gender: 0      
      }
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: you want something like people: [ {}, {}, {} ]? or just get the object from there?

Comment: I already have "people" (and that works on a list page) but for the single record, I just want "person". But I can get it to work by taking the 0 index of people, I'm fine with that too. It just doesn't seem as clean or logical.

Comment: check my answer, I think make sense to write an util function to parse the "people"

Answer (score 2):

`Person` is an `array`, that contains the `object` in which Name key is present, so you need to use `index` also, write it like this:

```
this.props.person && this.props.person.length ? this.props.person[0].Name : '';
```

Check this example:

```js
var data = {
      "person":[
                 {
                    "PersonID":1,
                    "Name":"John Smith",
                    "Gender":0
                  }
              ]
};

console.log('Name: ', data.person[0].Name);
```

Comment: yes, still have the issue. I'm afraid neither answer is helping. This is my raw redux state:

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are supposed to map the person detail foreach person's data.

on the PersonPage.js ,

map it as follows:

```
{
    this.props.person.map((p)=>{
    return (<PersonDetail person={p} />)
    })
}
```

Comment: looks logical, but gives me a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would make an util function like this:

```
const parsePeople = people => {

  if (people instanceof Array) return parsePeople(people.pop())

  return people

}


const people = [
  [{
    PersonID: 51,
    Name: 'John Smith',
    Gender: 0      
  }]
]


const person = parsePeople(people)

console.log(person) -> Object
```

Using recursion we check if people is an instance of `Array`, we call the function again using `people.pop()` which return the last element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

you have an array on your person data... you can only access that without the 0 using map...

example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (nextProps) => {
  var PersonID = nextProps.person ? nextProps.person.map(item => { return item.PersonID}) : ''; 
  var Name = nextProps.person ? nextProps.person.map(item => { return item.Name}) : ''; 

this.setState({
    PersonID,
    Name
  });
```

}

this is considering you only have 1 array on person.

Comment: sorry, I get a blank page with this error in the console:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of null

Comment: in that case you need to add validation on the return, since if that is the error.. your 1st render is empty yet... to correct that you need to include
`return item.Name?item.Name:''; ` instead of just `return item.Name` which should also be applied to PersonID..

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! It was a combination of two of the answers given:
In the PersonPage.js, I had to call the PersonDetails object like this:

```
<PersonDetail
            person={this.props.person[0]}           
          />
```

And this is the new MapStatetoProps:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  const { match } = props;
   if (match.params.PersonID) {    
         return {   
     person: state.people
    }    
 }
```

Thanks to those who answered. This drove me nuts.